# failed when install laravel and start artisan server

Tags: laravel

when I try to (before it I also got error when I install laravel, but I forget what the error said)

```
$ php artisan serve
```

I got this error

```
Mcrypt PHP Extension required
```

I really sure that I have install php5-mcrypt, and some people suggest to 
put mcrypt.ini to /etc/php5/mods-available

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 restart
```

But I have found that folder I can't find mcrypt.ini

Answer (score 0):

just check the folder /etc/php5/mods-available there is a file named mcrypt.ini.dpkg-new, you just need to rename or copy this file to the current directory with the name mcrypt.ini, and
start the server or install laravel